# Why can't I parse a date string saved to a variable in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

I need to run the following code in my Rails app:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone["Central Time (US & Canada)"].parse(game.date).utc.to_date.strftime("%_m/%d")[1..-1]
```

Where game is `@games.each do |game|`

But this doesn't work, I get the error, `TypeError: no implicit conversion of ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone into String`.

However, I can run:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone["Central Time (US & Canada)"].parse("2014-04-11 12am").utc.to_date.strftime("%_m/%d")[1..-1]
```

which returns "4/11"

How can I use the above code with `game.date' instead of the hard coded string?

**EDIT**

a Game object looks like the following (from db/seeds.rb):

```
Game.create(id: 9, date: "2014-04-11 12am", time: "705PM", opponent: "Jacksonville", away: false, event: "friday night fireworks")
```

**EDIT 2**

In the rails console when I do game.date it returns:

```
Fri, 11 Apr 2014 00:00:00 UTC +00:00
```

so it seems its not a string.

Comment: because in console `#to_s` being called on `Date` object in console.

Comment: Any way to parse the Date object?

Comment: @reknirt `game.date.to_s` should give you what you want

Comment: yes, use `Date::strptime` method

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To make what you're trying to do work, you need to convert your date to a string with `to_s`:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone["Central Time (US & Canada)"].parse(game.date.to_s).utc.to_date.strftime("%_m/%d")[1..-1]
```

However, you should consider whether this is really what you want to do.  As it stands now, this code is taking a date, converting it to a string, parsing the string to get back to the date, then converting it to a string a second time.  Are you sure you couldn't get by with something like this?

```
game.date.strftime(%_m/%d")[1..-1]
```

Answer (score 3):

`ActiveSupport::TimeZone.parse` needs a string and not a `Date` object example below:

```
 ActiveSupport::TimeZone["Central Time (US & Canada)"].parse(Date.current.to_s).utc.to_date.strftime("%_m/%d")[1..-1]
 #=> "4/11"
```

so change:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone["Central Time (US & Canada)"].parse(game.date).utc.to_date.strftime("%_m/%d")[1..-1]
```

to:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone["Central Time (US & Canada)"].parse(game.date.to_s).utc.to_date.strftime("%_m/%d")[1..-1]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use below string:

As refereed to documentation http://rubyinrails.com/2013/09/strftime-format-time-in-ruby/

```
game.date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M%P")
#output=> "2014-04-11 12am"
```

So in your loop you can use:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone["Central Time (US & Canada)"].parse(game.date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M%P")).utc.to_date.strftime("%_m/%d")[1..-1]
```